# How to deal with multiple form tags on one page for Product item creations?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I tried to find out a solution to manage multiple (two in my case) forms on one page while creating a new product item.

I would like to hear from you who'd managed to deal with the same issue.

This is my form:

[image]

Theoretically I want to upload the images with jQuery AJAX method once the UPLOAD QUEUE button is clicked, but it shouldn't intefer with the main `<form name="form">`.

What's the best way for this solution ?

**==== UPDATED =====**

Maybe there is a way to upload a specific `<input>` when clicking on Upload button  ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not wrapping the image upload tab with a form, since you are submitting it via AJAX anyway?

[**Besides, a form element should not contain other form elements.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

Next step would be to set your `Upload Queue` button's `type` attribute to `button`. That way, clicking it won't trigger the form it belong in.

Comment: yes, i already thinked about that, but wasn't sure how it would work when I will click on the **Save & Close** button which will trigger another form. I've updated the question. I wonder if changing btn `Upload queue` to `type="button"` like you said, could collect only `<input name="images">` while that input will seat on the main `<form>` ?

Comment: That's not possible. However you can serialize only a portion of a form via jQuery and do with it what you want: `jQuery('#images-tab *').serialize()` or `jQuery('#images-tab *').serializeArray()`. What AJAX upload library are you using? Does it really require you to hook into the `submit` event of a form?

Comment: thanks Bez, i will try that and will give you my feedback. And the library is: http://safron.su/playground/damnUploader/demo-bootstrap/

Comment: doing `.serialize()` won't catch any POST data for `input[type="file"]`, don't know why, so I used `ajaxFileUpload.js` plugin which creates the `iframe` and post a data from it. Thanks for the tip. btw if you update your answer with the suggestion of use an `<iframe>` tag, i would accept it.